# how to add dynamic image to td background image?

Tags: php

in this code i want to add $image variable to td background but i dont know if add it between quotes without any problems..or delete quotes..and how to get it from youtube video..thanks for helping

```
<table width="130" height="97">
<tbody><tr>

<td valign="center" width="130" align="center" background="showvideo.php_files/2_003.jpg" height="97">
<a href="http://www.mysite.com/video/watch.php?VDCID=42608">
<img src="showvideo.php_files/play_arrow.gif" alt=" Theme Song " border="0">
</a>
</td>
</tr>
</tbody></table>
```

Comment: I'm not sure if we quite understand what you're trying to accomplish. There's no "$image" anywhere... Maybe some sample php code and what you're trying to do, and/or what error it's throwing would help us.

Comment: man...i want to understand the logic how to add some variable between html tag..i put virtual code as example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there you go:

```
    <td valign="center" width="130" align="center" background="<?php echo $image; ?>" height="97"></td>
```